# Finding start of last line in a file?

Tags: ruby, file

For some reasons I have to find start of last line in a file, so far I've done this:

```
file.seek(-1,IO::SEEK_END)
while file.getc != "\n"
  file.seek(-2,IO::SEEK_CUR)
end
```

This is another way but much slower:

```
buff = file.readlines
file.seek(-(buff.pop).length,IO::SEEK_END)
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I'd use `tail -n 1 file` from the command line :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the position of the ends of all the lines in a file using

```
offsets = f.each.map { f.tell }
```

and clearly the start of the last line is the end of the penultimate line, i.e. `offsets[-2]`.

So to speed things up a bit, all you need to do is first to `seek` sufficiently far from the end that you are *bound* to have gone past the start of the last line, and then get a list in the same way.

Suppose your lines are all *guaranteed* to be less than eighty characters in length:

```
open('myfile') do |f|
  f.seek(-80, IO::SEEK_END)
  offsets = f.each.map { f.tell }
  puts offsets[-2]
end
```

Or if you know very little about the lengths of the lines in your file, you can iterate until you find you have captured two or more line endings. This code steps back eighty characters at a time from the end of the file until `offsets` has two or more entries.

```
open('myfile') do |f|
  start = 0
  offsets = []
  loop do
    start -= 80
    f.seek(start, IO::SEEK_END)
    offsets = f.each.map { f.tell }
    break if offsets.size >= 2
  end
  puts offsets[-2]
end
```

Note that there are some special boundary cases:

- `IO` will raise an error if you try to seek off the beginning of the file
- If your file has only one line then the value you want is zero, but this algorithm will never find it

Comment: Considering how fast the first suggested code should run, I'd go with it. It would have to be a huge file or really long lines to see much improvement by jumping to the end and working backwards. It's pretty safe to assume 80 or 132 for line lengths in a text file, but a CSV or TSV file could vary wildly from that, and cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: The last suggestion can easily, safely, quickly use a value like 1024 instead of 80. Ruby and the underlying OS should be able to pull in 1024 byes as fast as it can 80, and the higher number will more quickly find the answer in unexpectedly long lines. This is a case when the size of the I/O buffers should come in really handy.